# Is Zend Opcache automatically caching compiled version of PHP scripts?

Tags: linux, php, cache, opcache

I've enabled Zend Opcache. I expected it to compile and cache every single PHP script executed on my server but this doesn't seem to happen.

Did I misunderstood how this cache works or I'm missing something?

[image]

Comment: It seems the problem is related to suPhp http://stackoverflow.com/a/24985895/196210

Comment: Another very important answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22440496/196210